# How to catch request information in the python twisted xmlrpc_method?

Tags: python, twisted, xml-rpc

I've study the twisted xmlrpc tutorial: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/xmlrpc.html to setup a xmlrpc server for building my xmlrpc method, but I want to know some request information from client like ip address. Tutorials just tell my add `xmlrpc_` as prefix makes my method to be a remote procedure call. Does anyone know how to rewrite it? Any help will be appreciated. Or maybe I need to force client to send its ip as parameters?

```
def xmlrpc_some_method(self):
  if request.ip in bad_ips():
    return '404'
  else:
    return do_something()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used xmlrpc myself but by going through the source [1], it looks like you can decorate the function with `t.w.x.withRequest` [2] and then you will get `request` as the first argument to the function.

[1] http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.0.0/twisted/web/xmlrpc.py#L169

[2] http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-13.0.0/twisted/web/xmlrpc.py#L37